# JPA CriteriaSepcification IN clause

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, jpa-criteria

I'm using `SpringBoot 2.2.6` with `JPA` and I need to do query with `IN` clause as mentioned in Title. I have try with:

```
@Override
public Predicate toPredicate(Root<Distinta> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder builder) {
    
    List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();
    .....
    .....
    for (DistintaCriteria criteria : list) {
        switch(criteria.getOperation()) {
        case TEST:
            Join<Entity, JoinEntity> join = root.join("joinEntity");
            predicates.add(join.<Integer>get("id").in(criteria.getValue()));
    }
}
```

where `criteria.getValue()` is a `Integer[]` array but it doesn't work. Can you help me?

Thank you all.

**UPDATE**

If I try the same `Query` with `List<String>` it works! With Integer I had this error:

```
Unaware how to convert value [[2, 3, 4, 5] : java.util.ArrayList] to requested type [java.lang.Integer]
```

Answer (score 2):

I have solved as follows:

```
Join<Entity, JoinEntity> join = root.join("joinEntity");
Predicate in = join.get("id").in((List<Integer>)criteria.getValue());
predicates.add(in);
```

I don't know why with `List<String>` I don't need to cast.
Hope helps.

Answer (score 0):

For in clause we need to pass a list always.

You need to convert your `Integer array` to `Integer list` using `Java-8` like

`List<Integer> values = Arrays.asList(criteria.getValue())`

```
@Override
public Predicate toPredicate(Root<Distinta> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder builder) {
    
    List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();
    .....
    .....
    for (DistintaCriteria criteria : list) {
    
        List<Integer> values = Arrays.asList(criteria.getValue());
    
        switch(criteria.getOperation()) {
        case TEST:
            Join<Entity, JoinEntity> join = root.join("joinEntity");
            predicates.add(join.<Integer>get("id").in(values));
    }
}
```

In eclipse, we will get the warning like if we pass an array

`Type Integer[] of the last argument to a method in(Object...) doesn't exactly match the vararg parameter type. Cast to Object[] to confirm the non-varargs invocation, or pass individual arguments of type Object for a varargs invocation.`